# Finding the first and last rows that contain a black pixel, in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-2.x

I have a black and white image of a triangle (it contains only 0 and 255 pixel values).

[image]

I've converted it to a numpy array called `myArray`

Currently, I can find the `width` of the bottom of the triangle (the number of black pixels) by using this code:

```
width = (max(numpy.where(myArray == 0)[1])) - (min(numpy.where(myArray == 0)[1]))
```

If the triangle was flipped upside-down, `width` would then apply to the top of the upside-down triangle.

What i'm trying to do is determine if the triangle is pointing up or down.

I could do this by finding the first row that contains a black pixel, and counting the number of black pixels in that row, calling this `firstRow`

and finding the last row that contains a black pixel, and counting the number of black pixels in that row, calling that `lastRow`

Then, if `firstRow` `<` `lastRow`, the triangle is pointing up.

What is the best way to calculate `firstRow` and `lastRow`?

Comment: `np.where((myArray == 1).sum(axis=1)>0)` will give you the rows with black (0) points.

Comment: @Mstaino, thanks; that's giving me `(array([], dtype=int64),)` though

Comment: my bad: `myArray == 0` instead of `myArray == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `myArray` with 255 for black pixel such as

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., 255., 255., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

you can get all the rows with at least one black pixel with `np.where` after using `sum` on `axis=1`:

```
print (np.where(myArray.sum(axis=1)))
(array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

If you want to get the row with the maximum number of black pixels, you can use `np.argmax` still after `sum` on `axis=1`:

```
print (np.argmax(myArray.sum(axis=1)))
5
```

To know if the triangle is up or down, one way is to check if the `argmax` is the `np.max` element in the `np.where(myArray.sum(axis=1))`, then it would be up.

```
myArray_sum = myArray.sum(axis=1)
if np.max(np.where(myArray_sum)) == np.argmax(myArray_sum):
    print ('up')
else:
    print ('down')
```

If you want the first and last row, here is one way but it is related to the value of the black pixel.

```
myArray_sum = myArray.sum(axis=1)
firstRow = np.argmax(myArray_sum == 255)
lastRow = np.argmax(myArray_sum)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome information, but I may have been vague in my original post. `(np.where(myArray.sum(axis=1)))` lists every row, which makes no sense to me. I think it may be because this is a 2D array. When I print out the entire array, I get an array (like your example) for every row. Most are all `... 255 255 ...`, then towards the middle some `... 0 0 0 ...` are seen. Does this make sense to you? I apologize my my lack of knowledge here. `myArray.sum(axis=1)` returns an array with numbers I wouldn't expect, like `46920`

Comment: @yodish Do you mean that the white is symbolize by the value 255 in your array and the black by 0? or more globably that the triangle is made of 0? if yes, you can probably use the above method by changing the definition of `myArray_sum` by `myArray_sum = (255 - myArray).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: thank you! that does give me close to what i'm looking for. The only thing is, now, `np.argmax(myArray_sum)` is returning the first row that contains a black pixel in it and `np.argmax(myArray_sum ==255)` is returning `0`

Comment: `if np.max(np.where(myArray_sum)) == np.argmax(myArray_sum):` works just fine though, and I think that should get me over the hump. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @yodish at least something gives you the result you want. Not sure why `np.argmax(myArray_sum ==255)` is not returning the right row though. I'll give a try when I can.